# Confused about official Android documentation on Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I refer to the official Android documentation on using the Flow library in the [recommended app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#persist-data).

In the `UserRepository` class:

```kotlin
class UserRepository @Inject constructor(...) {
   fun getUser(userId: String): Flow<User> {
       refreshUser(userId)
       // Returns a Flow object directly from the database.
       return userDao.load(userId)
   }

   private suspend fun refreshUser(userId: String) {
       ...
   }

   ...
}
```

I don't understand how `refreshUser()`, which is a suspending function, can be called in `getUser()`, which is a non-suspending function. Perhaps I'm missing something.

I'm trying to create something very similar to this class and, as expected, I get a compilation error stating that the suspending function can be called only in another suspending function. What is the minimal change required to make this work, such that in `UserProfileViewModel`, I can keep the `LiveData<User>` variable `user` as it already is:

```kotlin
val user = userRepository.getUser(userId).asLiveData()
```

Comment: May be the return type `Flow` did the magic (I guess).

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a `suspend` function within `non-suspend` function, so the function `getUser()` has an error `Suspend function 'refreshUser' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`. To make this error disappear add `suspend` keyword:

```
suspend fun getUser(userId: String): Flow<User> { ... }
```

To make your second code work you need to use [`liveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) builder.

```
val user = liveData<User> { 
    emitSource(getUser(userId).asLiveData())
}
```

In `liveData` builder you can call `suspend` functions, in particular `getUser(userId)`.